# I unable to get data from 2 fields from db in ListView form using cursor Adaptor

Tags: android, database, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

I want,two field's data from database on list view using `Cursoradapter`.
I am able to fetch single field's data from db using `Cursoradapter`.

Here i want to show two field's data in list view i.e. Constants.file_name and Constants.url_path..

```
dba = new MyDB(this);

dba.open();

mQuery = "Select " + Constants.DOCU_ID + ","
        + Constants.FILE_NAME
        + ","
        + Constants.URL_PATH
        + " from "
        + Constants.TABLE_NAME_DOCU 
        + " where " + Constants.KEY_ID_CONTACT_DOCU
        + " = " + mContactKeyID;

c = dba.getResults(mQuery);
startManagingCursor(c);

String[] resultColumns;

if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {

}

int[] textviews = new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};
resultColumns = new String[] { Constants.FILE_NAME, Constants.URL_PATH };
mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c,
        resultColumns, textviews);
this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);

getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

here i am retrieving  data using cursor..but url_path is not retrie

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onItemClick(parent, view, position, id);
    final Cursor c = (Cursor) mAdapter
            .getItem(position);
    uname = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.FILE_NAME));
    docuId = c.getInt(c
            .getColumnIndex(Constants.DOCU_ID));
    urlPath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.URL_PATH));
```

logCat error

```
     09-23 17:56:07.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2776): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 17:56:07.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2776): Process: com.cbsinfosys.FieldWorkMobility, PID: 2776
09-23 17:56:07.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2776): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
09-23 17:56:07.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2776):     at com.cbsinfosys.FieldWorkMobility.ViewBrowse$1.onClick(ViewBrowse.java:383)
09-23 17:56:07.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2776):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
09-23 17:56:07.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2776):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
09-23 17:56:07.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2776):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
09-23 17:56:07.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2776):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-23 17:56:07.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2776):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
09-23 17:56:07.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2776):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
09-23 17:56:07.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2776):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-23 17:56:07.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2776):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-23 17:56:07.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2776):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
09-23 17:56:07.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2776):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: and what is wrong? you can debug the `Cursor` data with `DatabaseUtils#dumpCurrentRow`

Comment: in my case here one of this field show empty on listView

Comment: did you call `DatabaseUtils#dumpCurrentRow` inside `onItemClick`?

Comment: can u write the syntax i dont understand...

Comment: call `DatabaseUtils#dumpCurrentRow` method inside `onItemClick` method, what is unclear here?

Comment: actually i'm new in android

Comment: still its not working

Comment: did you read `dumpCurrentRow` documentation?

Comment: yes this is used for print cursors current row

Comment: and what does it print?

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@5786cb3  with blank data on listView but its clickable and invisible  here only one Fields item shows i.e. url_path the other one comes but its invisible and  when i click on this invisible error through ...i added error in top

Comment: ok i f you dont want to answer what it prints, it is your problem... not mine

Comment: @pskink sir I answered you... it says  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@5786cb3     this System.print.ln in logcat

Comment: and i put up logcat error when i click invisible item in listviews

Comment: call **dumpCurrentRow** not **System.println** ! where did i say to call **System.println** ?!?

Comment: I called this method public void dumpCurrentRow(Cursor c){      Sop(c)                           } from onitemclick...

Comment: and what do you see on the logcat when you call `dumpCurrentRow` ?

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@5786cb3  this line

Comment: no: `dumpCurrentRow` prints something like [this](http://pastebin.com/7ZZS55Jt) on the logcat

Comment: @pskink  i think sir, i called dumpCurrentRow in wrong why